# Univocally identifying Android users to offer a limited time license

Tags: android, user-identification

I would like to publish an Android app with 2-years time support (this is due to API costs). After 2 years, the user has to buy the app again (if he wants).

There are at least 3 problems:

1. I want it to be easy and effortless for the user: so no "registration form" (if possible).
2. The app should work on other devices connected with the same Google account (as every payed app).
3. The app should not work if the user sells his device: so using device's IMEI isn't a very good solution.

I think that the definitive solution would be univocally identifying the user, but the question is: how to do that?
Do you think that AccountManager could be a solution?

Note that the app needs to connect to my server in order to work, so the solution can be implemented both client and/or server side.

Comment: Unequivocally? Otherwise what does univocally mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to uniquely identify the user using his/her phone number. This is what Wavesecure does.

This does have some implications:

a) your app cannot work on a wifi only tablet.
b) you will have to provide a way for users to migrate phone numbers in case they happen to change phones.

Answer (score 0):

You said that:

> The app should work on other devices connected with the same Google account (as every payed app).

Use the google account.
When the app starts have him choose a google account and save the account ID (the email address) server side.
Also make sure the user can change the referenced account, it should not make any difference, as long as you allow just one account per user.

Ideally, as time passes by, you may want to track the active installations for each user, and limit the number of devices (model name, IMEI if available, OS version etc) to prevent fake account sharing. But that's something you can do later.